# Pandas how to parse 'datetimeoffset' values from SQL Server that are in binary format

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, database, pandas, datetime

I am querying a SQL Server database that has a column of type `datetimeoffset`.  I am using 'pyodbc' and SQL Server 2017. The datetime is being returned as strings as follows:

```
"b'\xe3\x07\n\x00\x0e\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x05\x00@\xe1\x9d\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00'"
```

Pandas doesn't recognize it as a timestamp and I have tried using Python 3 'struct' module to unpack it like this:

```
import struct
raw = 'b\xe3\x07\n\x00\x0e\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x05\x00@\xe1\x9d\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00'
unpacked, = struct.unpack('<Q', raw)
```

That errors out because 'raw' is a string. If I enter the string directly as an argument in 'unpack' it errors out because of wrong number of bytes.

How do I convert the column values to pandas datetime?

Additional Note:
This [site](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) indicates that the SQL Server uses a particular type that pyodbc doesn't handle natively as suggested by [mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert).  That said, they seem to have no problem retrieving a human-readable value.

[SOLVED]   So the solution at this [site](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) does work.  TIL: when adding the converter you need to get the type as an integer, in this case '-155'.  This [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements?view=sql-server-ver15) has the integer codes for some other types

Comment: This doesn't even resemble the native TDS format of a `DATETIMEOFFSET`; I suspect `pyodbc` or the underlying driver simply mess up trying to turn the bytes into something meaningful. Make sure to use [the most recent version of the ODBC driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) available for your platform and use it in the connection string/DSN (`DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`), the default drivers are often woefully out of date and do not support the newer types.

Comment: tnx.  yes I'm using driver 17 (that got edited to 'SQL Server 2017').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution at this [site](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) does work.  TIL: when adding the converter you need to get the type as an integer, in this case '-155'.  This [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements?view=sql-server-ver15) has the integer codes for some other types